# When overriding the << (stream) operator, debug goes into std's << impl instead?

Tags: c++, streaming, overriding, iostream

This question has been partially answered: the solution is that in one of my class's fields, specifically _escape, has UB. However, it is still unknown why Visual Studio's stack trace does not display the operator<< function nor does the debugger find it - almost as if there was an optimization(I disabled optimizations) to remove the symbol and merge it with the print function.

## What I already know

I have seen all the popular posts on SO about << operator overload. I have followed all the basic semantics. This isn't a duplicate question of any of the popular posts.

To override the << operator, one needs to define a function with the general format of:

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const MyObject& dt)
```

I have done so in my program,

I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 for this project, and using the debugger to try to step into the << operator function. However, it never gets inside of the function that I defined as follows:

```
std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& os, const EscapeStr& t)
{
    t.print(os);
    return os;
}
```

where EscapeStr is a class I defined with the following function definition for `print`:

```
void print(std::ostream& os) const { 
    for (int i = 0; i < _elem.length(); i++) {
        char c = _elem[i];
        if (_delim[c]) {
            for (int j = 0; j < _escLen; j++) {
                os << _escape[j];
            }
        }
        os << _elem[i];
    }
}
```

## The problem

I see the print() function being called here using the VS debugger, but I cannot observe the program entering the scope of my overridden <<, but rather it's going into the std definition of <<, with the following signature:

```
template<class _Traits> inline
    basic_ostream<char, _Traits>& operator<<(
        basic_ostream<char, _Traits>& _Ostr,
        const char *_Val);  // insert NTBS into char stream
```

This is extremely weird, because only the ostream override operator has access to my public function currently. Is Visual Studio just lying?

I don't understand what's going on, as one of my other overloads do work, and the signature isn't even exact(without the const and reference):

```
/// ostream operator for indent
std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream &os, indent x)
{
    static const std::string spaces("    ");
    while(x.d--) {
        os << spaces; 
    }
    return os;
}
```

As a result, my program is exhibiting some UB(reading the std library code would drive me insane). Here's an ideone to show the UB: https://ideone.com/jxro5s . Any help would be greatly appreciated.

## Extra information for MVCE and clarity

```
const static char _delims[] = { '\\', '"' };
const static std::vector<char> delims(_delims, _delims + 2);

class EscapeStr {
    const static unsigned short MAX_CHAR = 256;

    std::string &_elem;
    bool _delim[MAX_CHAR];
    const char* _escape;
    int _escLen;
public:
    EscapeStr(std::string &elem,
        const std::vector<char> &delim = std::vector<char>(1, '"'),
        const std::string &escape = "\\") :
        _elem(elem),
        _escape(escape.c_str()),
        _escLen(escape.size())
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < MAX_CHAR; i++) {
            _delim[i] = false;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < delim.size(); i++) {
            _delim[delim[i]] = true;
        }
    }
    void print(std::ostream& os) const {
        for (int i = 0; i < _elem.length(); i++) {
            char c = _elem[i];
            if (_delim[c]) {
                for (int j = 0; j < _escLen; j++) {
                    os << _escape[j];
                }
            }
            os << _elem[i];
        }
    }
};
```

Here is an image of the stack trace - no sign of the << operator.
[image]

EDIT: To predict future comments/posts about me not using std::quoted - I'm trying to make the program compatible with versions less than C++11.

Comment: If `print()` is being called then surely your overridden `operator<<` is called? Also, your `operator<<` should be declared `const`.

Comment: Looks like your class has a cast operator, which gets invoked to convert an `EscapeStr` to `char const*`. It's most likely that the your `operaro<<` function is not declared at the time you call it.

Comment: @ArchbishopOfBanterbury I would think so as well, but I put breakpoints on every line of that operator overload and it never stepped in.

Comment: An MCVE should be complete and verifiable. We can't compile this for ourselves and see the error. And before the whole definition of `EscapeStr` gets added, it is likely that most of it does not affect this behaviour and can be removed (in the spirit of an MCVE being minimal).

Comment: @RSahu It does not have a cast operator unfortunately. The only public function(in fact, the only function other than the ctor) is the print function.

Comment: @chris my apologies, I'll include the implementation of the class and some extra code for MVCE. Thanks for the advice. I have added the impl of the class. It's just the stack overflow community is often very tl;dr and if I supply too much code noone would want to read it, so I often add too little information on accident.

Comment: One wild guess: in which `namespace` did you put your override?

Comment: The whole point of a MCVE is that we can reproduce the error, because [I currently can't](https://ideone.com/K82m8U). Does the string get printed? Or is it just not going into `operator<<` when you debug?

Comment: @lorro it's the same place as my other `operator<<`. They're both inside a namespace called avro(Everything that uses the EscapeStr, including itself is in the namespace). @Rakete1111 It's not currently going into `operator<<` when I debug. The string that's supposed to be "escaped" shouldn't be printed correctly in fact. One second, I'll try fiddling on ideone. The behavior that your code is making might be UB.

Comment: @Rakete1111 The fiddling is now in the post. There's no output from the stringstream that took the rdbuf() of my ostream.

Comment: FWIW, your Ideone example [does call your `operator<<`](https://ideone.com/o0lgQS).

Comment: You're right. It was Visual Studios lying to me, which threw me off. Thank you though! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the first thing to do is fix the undefined behavior reading from `_escape` after the temporary string to which is points has been destroyed. The best option in my mind is to replace `const char* _escape; int _escLen;` with `std::string escape_;` and then your for loop becomes `os << escape_;`. Since we're talking about UB here, anything could happen including not calling your custom `operator<<`.

Comment: Ah - you're right. I overlooked that mistake since I was so focused on trying to get the `operator<<` to work. I'll fix that and report back any results. Thanks for the catch!

EDIT: Fixed, but I still can't see the operator<< going into my function. However, the output is as expected. Might this be an issue from visual studio? I'll leave this question open for a small while to encourage some discussion about the visual studio debugger, but I'll likely accept your answer since it fixed my output.